# Initialize array of std::vector with sizes

Tags: c++, initialization

This won't compile, because the constructor that takes the size (something like `vector::vector( size_t )`) is `explicit`:

```
constexpr auto n = 16;
std::vector< std::unique_ptr< int > > v[ 2 ]{ { n }, {} };
```

So how can I initialize `v[ 0 ]` with `n` default constructed elements, and leave `v[ 1 ]` empty?

Comment: Why would you want to have a vector of unique_ptr's that (if initialised) each reference a single dynamically allocated `int`???

Comment: I substituted my class by int for simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct temporary objects explicitly, e.g.

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr< int > > v[ 2 ]{ std::vector< std::unique_ptr< int > >{ n }, {} };
```